# Am i implementing redux correctly in my ReactNative app?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am implementing a mobile application using ReactNative with Redux, the app that i am implementing looks like that:

```
Login (screen) 
|--> Search for an object (screen)
   |--> Show that object and edit it (screen)
      |--> Take 2 photos (each photo a screen)
         |--> A last screen for make a new object and save it
```

The above flow shows how each screen do their work and pass to the next screen.

My application state is the next:

```
{
  auth: {
    logged: false,
    token: ''
  },
  somethingOfSideBar...
}
```

But i feel i am doing the things in the wrong way, because most of the screens have their own state, by example **searchSomethingScreen** fetch data from the server, check if it is valid and enable to pass to the next screen. I feel i am not doing the things in the **Redux** way, it suppose to make actions that change the entire state application, but i feel i do not need more state than i have. For me the global things are auth data and sidebar (because it is present across the entire application).

Should i make actions for every screen change? 
Should i put more information in the global state application?

A one more thing, i have a AppContainer component which is used in connect to have access to the store, but i am passing parts of the state and the actions as well as children properties and i feel this is wrong as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel the [Redux Reddit tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html) may be useful to you. It certainly was for me.

> But i feel i am doing the things in the wrong way, because most of the screens have their own state, by example searchSomethingScreen fetch data from the server, check if it is valid and enable to pass to the next screen.

Used in the *Redux* way, API requests and their successful completion should each map to one action. Change the application state appropriately (in your reducing function) on each action and views/screens bound to your store will re-render. So if you're making an API request:

- Create a `Search` container, mapping state `searchResults` to `props` and binding a `Search` component. (For example, see [this container](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#containersfilterlinkjs).)
- Fire action `REQUEST_SEARCH` with search term on user input.
- AJAX request is fired.
- AJAX request successfully completes. Fire action `RECEIVE_SEARCH` with search results.
- `SearchReducer` stores search results.
- Bound `Search` component re-renders with search results.

> Should i make actions for every screen change? Should i put more information in the global state application?

As a general rule, yes. But sometimes I've used component state (without dispatching an action) to store state that is local to the component (e.g. updating a text field).

> A one more thing, i have a AppContainer component which is used in connect to have access to the store, but i am passing parts of the state and the actions as well as children properties and i feel this is wrong as well.

In general, higher level components should be containers, which inject state into the stateless components via props. You can have more than one containers and they work like components, so you can nest a container in another container. I encourage you to have a look at the docs, as it was very useful for me. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it gave me some things to begin refactoring my app. When you say: AJAX is fired, should i make the fetch call inside the "REQUEST_SEARCH" action?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The [`fetch()` is a Then-able](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#handling-the-response) so you can add a success callback that fires `RECEIVE_SEARCH`. :)